# Loop through rows and merge cells over 5 columns in Openpyxl

Tags: python, merge, openpyxl

I'd like to loop through each row of my worksheet and merge columns G to K for each row.

So it looks like this:
[image: Like in row 1]

So far I have this:

```
for i in (ws.iter_rows(max_row=ws.max_row, max_col=11)):
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=2, start_column=7, end_row=2, end_column=11)
```

I know this only works with the 2nd row as that's what's specified in the merge cells function. Is there a way I can use merge_cells without specifying the start and end row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a for loop that starts at 1 and goes up to and including the max row:

```py
for row_num in range(1, ws.max_row+1):
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=row_num, start_column=7, end_row=row_num, end_column=11)
```

Comment: Ah yes of course! I didn't think of that, my mind went to iter_rows instead! Thanks!

Comment: No problemo. You can also use `openpyxl.utils.cell.column_index_from_string("G")` and `openpyxl.utils.cell.column_index_from_string("K")`, which return 7 and 11 respectively. It might make your code clearer.